# First order ordinary differential equation of specific type

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I got stuck with this first order ODE problem
$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\sqrt{\sin^2y(x)+ay(x)}$, where "a" is a positive real number.

Is there any specific type of substitution to solve this kind of ODE.

Comment: i don't found any substitution to solve this ode maybe a otherone

Comment: The differential equation is separable. You want to find a primitive to $1/\sqrt{\sin^2 y+ay}$ (with respect to $y$). I've not seen that one...